# Porque luego de enviar variables por ajax y recuperar por php se vuelen indefinidas.

Tags: php, ajax, bootstrap, mysqli, highcharts

Tengo dos select y una caja de texto, por medio de los cuales envio valores a consulta.php los valores seleccionados de los select son los mas importantes para mi pues depende de que lo que usuario seleccione eso valores seran pasados a unas consultas con las que sus valor ayudaran a mostrar unas graficas. Cuando lo hago todo a través de un form con action="php/consultar.php", NO existe problema, pero yo quiero que el resultado no se recargue y que se muestre en la misma pagina.

```html
<?php  
include 'conexion/conexion.php';
$anios_fiscal = "SELECT * FROM periodo ORDER BY nombre_periodo ASC";
$query1 = mysqli_query($conexion_mysql, $anios_fiscal);
$opc_periodo = '<option value="0">Informaci&oacute;n del periodo</option>';
$row_periodo="";
while ($row_periodo = mysqli_fetch_object($query1)){
 $opc_periodo.='<option value="'.$row_periodo->nombre_periodo.'">'.$row_periodo->nombre_periodo.'</option>';
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title></title>
 <link rel="alternate" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async defer></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async defer></script>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#editarot_btn").click(function(){
        var anios_fiscales = $("#anios_fiscales").val();
        var trimestres = $("#trimestres").val();
        var nombre = $("#nombre").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "php/consultar.php",
            data: {anios_fiscales:anios_fiscales, trimestres:trimestres, nombre:nombre},
            success: function(){
                alert("Ha sido ejecutada la acción.");
            }
        });
    });
});
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <form action="" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
   <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-2">
     <select class="form-control" name="anios_fiscales" id="anios_fiscales">
      <?php echo $opc_periodo; ?>
     </select>    
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-2">
     <select class="form-control" name="trimestres" id="trimestres">
      <option value="Q-1">Trimestre 1</option>
      <option value="Q-2">Trimestre 2</option>
      <option value="Q-3">Trimestre 3</option>
      <option value="Q-4">Trimestre 4</option>
     </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
     <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" class="form-control nombre">
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
     <button type="button" id="editarot_btn" class="btn btn-success editarot_btn">Consultar 
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span>
     </button>     
    </div>
   </div>

  </form>

 </div>
 <div id="contenedor"></div>


</body>
</html>
<!-- <script src="js/funciones.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async defer></script> -->
```

Aquí esta el código de consulta.php.

```html
<?php  
include '../conexion/conexion.php';
$anios_fiscal_ = $_POST["anios_fiscales"];
$periodo = $_POST["trimestres"];
$text = $_POST["nombre"];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title></title>
<body>
 <div id="contenedor">
  <h1>hola</h1>
  <?php 
  echo $anios_fiscal_; 
  echo "<br>";
  echo $periodo;
  echo "<br>";
  echo $text;
  echo "<br>";
  $don_nac_id50 = "SELECT respuesta FROM respuestas WHERE oficina='UP4' AND periodo='$anios_fiscal_' AND trimestre='$periodo' AND id='RRHH2_ID23'";
  $result_nac_id50 = mysqli_query($conexion_mysql, $don_nac_id50);
  if ($fila=mysqli_fetch_object($result_nac_id50)) {echo $respuesta_don_nac_id50_Q1 = $fila->respuesta;}
  echo "<br>";
  $don_nac_Q2 = "SELECT respuesta FROM respuestas WHERE id='DonNac_ID50' AND oficina='OCD' AND periodo='$anios_fiscal_' AND trimestre='$periodo'";
  $result_nac_Q2 = mysqli_query($conexion_mysql, $don_nac_Q2);
  if ($fila=mysqli_fetch_object($result_nac_Q2)) {echo $respuesta_don_nac_id50_Q2 = $fila->respuesta;}
  echo "<br>";
  echo $total = (($respuesta_don_nac_id50_Q1/$respuesta_don_nac_id50_Q2)*100);
  echo "<br>";
  $don_nac_Q3 = "SELECT respuesta FROM respuestas WHERE id='DonNac_ID50' AND oficina='OCD' AND periodo='$anios_fiscal_' AND trimestre='$periodo'";
  $result_nac_Q3 = mysqli_query($conexion_mysql, $don_nac_Q3);
  if ($fila=mysqli_fetch_object($result_nac_Q3)) {echo $respuesta_don_nac_id50_Q3 = $fila->respuesta;}
  echo "<br>";
  $don_nac_Q4 = "SELECT respuesta FROM respuestas WHERE id='DonNac_ID51' AND oficina='OCD' AND periodo='$anios_fiscal_' AND trimestre='$periodo'";
  $result_nac_Q4 = mysqli_query($conexion_mysql, $don_nac_Q4);
  if ($fila=mysqli_fetch_object($result_nac_Q4)) {echo $respuesta_don_nac_id50_Q4 = $fila->respuesta;}
  echo "<bR>";
  echo $total2 = (($respuesta_don_nac_id50_Q3/$respuesta_don_nac_id50_Q4)*100);;
  ?>
  <div style="width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
      <div id="container-speed" style="width: 300px; height: 200px; float: left"></div>
      <div id="container-rpm" style="width: 300px; height: 200px; float: left"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

El resultado que obtengo me hace ver que mis variables no están definidas, por favor necesito ayuda.

Este es un resultado que veo en pantalla, en donde están los errores se deben de mostrar los valores seleccionados. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Eso normalmente ocurre cuando los error display estan en modo estricto para PHP, podrías utilizar isset de la siguiente manera: 

if(isset($_POST["anios_fiscales"]))$anios_fiscal_ = 
 $_POST["anios_fiscales"];

Comment: se llama consulta.php o consultar.php ?

Comment: Todo parece indicar que los datos no se están pasando al archivo `consultar.php`. Verifica que esta sería la ruta correcta del archivo `php/consultar.php` con respecto al lugar desde donde lo llamas. Según esto, el archivo debería estar dentro de una carpeta llamada `php` que se encontraría en la misma carpeta del archivo desde el cual haces la llamada Ajax.

Comment: estas haciendo todo mal, primero no puedes enviar una peticion ajax a un archivo estructurado con html pues recuerda que ajax va a imprimir como respuesta lo primero que retorne tu archivo, que en este caso es el **HOLA**, en todo caso, debes utilizar un archivo con php puro, ejecutar tus consultas, estructurar la respuesta, enviarla al ajax y procesar dicha respuesta con ajax

Comment: por ello recibes esos errores, pues ajax muestra la respuesta de tu archivo, al no ejecutarse las querys, pues inmediatamente retorna los errores asi como el html impreso en el.

Comment: Se llama consultar.php Juan Daniel

Comment: El detalle radica en que si por ejemplo yo uso <form action="php/consultar.php" method="post"></form>, me arroga los resultados deseados en otra pagina, pero yo los necesito que los cargue en la misma pantalla sin que me abra otra pagina, no se si me doy a entender.

Comment: Carlos Quintero que solución me puedes proponer tú.